# How to match string with pattern in a Bash case statement?

Tags: bash

Hey I want to do different things depending on the content of a variable, however I only care about the end of the string.
If I have a string `1. unit test` for instance I only want to know if it ends with `unit test`.

What I found in the `man bash` section about `case` is that it matches against patterns, and in the pattern matching section `*` is described to match with any string.

I don't understand why the following example is not working:

```bash
case "1. unit test" in
"* unit test")
  echo 1;;
esac
```

If `*` matches with any string then it matches with `1.`.

What am I not understanding and how could I check for the last part of the variable?
Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Don’t quote the asterisk: `*" unit test")`

Comment: Keep `*` outside so `*" unit test"`

Comment: ah yes that works, thanks :). I tried completely without quotes and got syntax errors. But like that it works